# LruCache метод put возвращает null

Tags: android

Всем привет! Скажите кто знает почему метод put Lrucache возвращает null вместо кэшированного изображения. Вот код:

```
...
Bitmap imageQwer = memoryCache.get(urldisplay);
if (imageQwer != null) {
   mIcon11 = imageQwer;
} else if (imageQwer == null) {
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
Bitmap image = null;

image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
int qwer = image.getByteCount(); // размер изображения в байтах получается 32400 байт
                                  // размер выделенного кэша получается 4194304, так         что памяти точно хватает для размещения одной тестовой картинки.
mIcon11 = memoryCache.put(urldisplay,image);// memoryCache.put возвращает null 
mIcon11 = image;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте немного [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html#put(K, V)). Там есть ключевой момент

> > **Returns**
> > the previous value mapped by key.

Перевожу - возвращает предыдущее значение, которое было закреплено за этим ключём. Если Там раньше не было никакого значения (а это скорее всего так), то и будет null.

Comment: Всё понятно. Спасибо вам огромное.